# Replace array elements based on dictionary in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dictionary like this :

```
var iso_map = {'AFG':'AF','ALB':'AL','DZA':'DZ','ASM':'AS','AND':'AD','AGO':'AO','AIA':'AI','ATA':'AQ','ATG':'AG'}
```

I have an array like this :

```
var isoCodes = ['AFG','AFG','AFG','AGO,'AGO','AFG','AFG','AND','AGO']
```

I want to replace the above array to give me an output like this:

```
var isoCodes - ['AF','AF','AF','AO,'AO','AF','AF','AD','AO']
```

Comment: simple map().....

Comment: `isoCodes = isoCodes.map(i=>iso_map[i]);` easy home work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use map

```js
var iso_map = {'AFG':'AF','ALB':'AL','DZA':'DZ','ASM':'AS','AND':'AD','AGO':'AO','AIA':'AI','ATA':'AQ','ATG':'AG'};

var isoCodes = ['AFG','AFG','AFG','AGO','AGO','AFG','AFG','AND','AGO']

var result = isoCodes.map(x => iso_map[x]);

console.log(result);
```